# Why does GraphQL only query 10 entries when using Custom Post Types?

Tags: wordpress, graphql, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

Not sure if this is a silly question but I am trying to query Custom Post Types from WordPress using GraphQL, there Custom Post Types also contain Advanced Custom Fields.

As you can see here I have published 17 in total:

[image]

My query to graphQL looks like this:

```
const GET_ALL_MEDIA = gql`
  query MyQuery {
    slumpMedias {
      edges {
        node {
          title
          slumpMeta {
            image {
              mediaItemUrl
            }
            audio1 {
              mediaItemUrl
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

For whatever reason I only get 10 entries that return, the most recent ones that I have published:

[image]

10 entries only appear as well when using the GraphQL IDE.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? I've checked the settings on WordPress and everything seems normal.

Using:

**Custom Post Type UI**, **WP GraphQL**, **WPGraphQL for Advanced Custom Fields**, **Advanced Custom Fields** as plugins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, it only pulls through the first 10, specify the limit of how much you want in the query

```
    {  
      slumpMedias (first:100)  {
          edges  {
            node {
              title
              slumpMeta {
                image {
                  mediaItemUrl
                }
                audio1 {
                  mediaItemUrl
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
    }
```